Two-body operators in second-quantized form
I'm currently reading through Altland and Simons' book "Condensed Matter Field Theory" (2nd ed.), where in chapter 2, page 49 they derive the form of two-body second-quantized operators. Specifically, they consider a symmetric two-body potential and go through the following derivation (here, the $\textbf{r}_i$ are labeling the positions of each particle, i.e. this is not in the occupation number representation):
$$
a^\dagger(\textbf{r})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}')a(\textbf{r}')a(\textbf{r})|\textbf{r}_1,\textbf{r}_2,...,\textbf{r}_N\rangle=a^\dagger(\textbf{r})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}')a(\textbf{r}')a(\textbf{r})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)|0\rangle
\\ =\sum_{n=1}^N\zeta^{n-1}\delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_n)a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_n)a^\dagger(\textbf{r}')a(\textbf{r}')a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_{n-1})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_{n+1})...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)|0\rangle
\\=\sum_{n=1}^N\zeta^{n-1}\delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_n)\sum_{m\neq n}^N\delta(\textbf{r}'-\textbf{r}_m)a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_n)a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_{n-1})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_{n+1})...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)|0\rangle
\\=\sum_{n,m \neq n}^N\delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_n)\delta(\textbf{r}'-\textbf{r}_m)|\textbf{r}_1,\textbf{r}_2,...,\textbf{r}_N\rangle.
$$
I'm pretty confused by this derivation. 1) Why are sums appearing at all in lines 2 and 3? If all we're doing is moving creation/annihilation operators past each other, we should at most only be getting delta functions right? 2) If the delta function in line 2 is produced due to commuting/anticommuting $a(\textbf{r})$ with $a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_n)$, then why is there still an $a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_n)$ in that product?
I've been guessing that 1) has to do with this not being the occupation number representation, and 2) is because $a^\dagger(\textbf{r})$ and $a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_n)$ are equivalent with the Dirac delta as a coefficient, but I'm unsure. Help with 1) is especially appreciated.

What is $\zeta$ supposed to represent?

Have you checked e.g. the $N=2$ or $N=3$ case already? In the third edition only the first and last line are written, btw.

@hft It's +1 if dealing with bosons and -1 if dealing with fermions.

@TobiasFünke I did write down $N=2$, it's no less vague.

You get a sum of $N(N-1)$ terms because you have to commute (or anti-commute) the $a_r$ past $N$ different creation operators. Then for each term in that sum you have to commute (or anti-commute) the $a_{r'}$ past $N-1$ different creation operators.


$$
a^\dagger(\textbf{r})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}')a(\textbf{r}')a(\textbf{r})|\textbf{r}_1,\textbf{r}_2,...,\textbf{r}_N\rangle=a^\dagger(\textbf{r})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}')a(\textbf{r}')a(\textbf{r})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)|0\rangle
\\ =\sum_{n=1}^N\zeta^{n-1}\delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_n)a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_n)a^\dagger(\textbf{r}')a(\textbf{r}')a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_{n-1})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_{n+1})...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)|0\rangle
\\=\sum_{n=1}^N\zeta^{n-1}\delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_n)\sum_{m\neq n}^N\delta(\textbf{r}'-\textbf{r}_m)a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_n)a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_{n-1})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_{n+1})...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)|0\rangle
\\=\sum_{n,m \neq n}^N\delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_n)\delta(\textbf{r}'-\textbf{r}_m)|\textbf{r}_1,\textbf{r}_2,...,\textbf{r}_N\rangle.
$$
I'm pretty confused by this derivation. 1) Why are sums appearing at all in lines 2 and 3?

The sums appear because you need to commute (or anti-commute) an $a(\mathbf{r})$ past $N$ different $a^\dagger(\mathbf{r}_i)$ operators. Commutators are a bit like derivatives in this sense (a bit like the product rule of differentiation). For example:
$$
[A,BCD] = [A,B]CD + B[A,C]D + BC[A,D] 
$$
or, as a second example:
$$
[A,B_1 B_2 B_3\ldots B_N]
$$
$$ = [A,B_1]B_2\ldots B_N + B_1[A,B_2]\ldots B_N + B_1B_2[A,B_3]\ldots B_N + \ldots + B_1\ldots B_{N-1}[A,B_N]\;.
$$
For fermionic operators, the analogous useful identity is:
$$
[A,BCD] = \{A,B\}CD - B\{A,C\}D + BC\{A,D\}\;,
$$
so you still get a sum of terms, but each picks up a sign according to "how far" the operator had to move down the line to anti-commute.


If all we're doing is moving creation/annihilation operators past each other, we should at most only be getting delta functions right?

You get a delta function for each commutator. For fermions you get a delta function and you pick up a sign depending on where in the product your anti-commutator is located.
When you commute the $a(\mathbf{r})$ you get a sum with $N$ terms, each of which has a delta function and $N-1$ creation operators.
When you commute the $a(\mathbf{r}')$ you get a second sum with $N-1$ terms for each of the $N$ terms in your first sum.

For example, for bosons:
$$
a^\dagger(\textbf{r})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}')a(\textbf{r}')a(\textbf{r})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)|0\rangle
$$
$$
=a^\dagger(\textbf{r})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}')a(\textbf{r}')
\left\{
[a(\textbf{r}),a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)]a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_2)...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)
+
a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)[a(\textbf{r}),a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_2)]...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)
+\ldots
+
a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_2)...[a(\textbf{r}),a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)]
\right\}|0\rangle
$$
$$
=a^\dagger(\textbf{r})a^\dagger(\textbf{r}')
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
[a(\textbf{r}),a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)]\left([a(\mathbf{r'}),a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_2)]...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)\right. &  +\left.a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_2)...[a(\mathbf{r'}),a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)]\right) + \\
[a(\textbf{r}),a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_2)]\left([a(\mathbf{r'}),a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)]...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)\right. &  +\left.a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)...[a(\mathbf{r'}),a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)]\right) + \\
+\ldots \\
+
[a(\textbf{r}),a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_N)]\left([a(\mathbf{r'}),a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)]...a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_{N-1})\right. &  +\left.a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_1)...[a(\mathbf{r'}),a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_{N-1})]\right)
\end{matrix}
\right\}
$$

Ah, for some reason I thought it was the daggered operators that were being pulled to the left, not the $a(\textbf{r})$ being pulled to the right to annihilate the vacuum. that makes sense.
And is my understanding of 2) correct?

Regarding "2)" there is still one annihilation operator $a(\mathbf{r}')$ on line 2 since at this point only $a(\mathbf{r})$ has been commuted through.

I was asking about the $a^\dagger(\textbf{r}_n)$ on line 2.

Regarding that $a^\dagger(\vec r_n)$: Yes, the $\vec r$ can be replaced by $\vec r_n$ because of  the delta function. @KandC
